# Android - Web Server Communication

Tags: java, android, sockets, servlets, webserver

I would like to create a dummy application for connecting my Android phone to my latop and printing out messages through the browser. (Imagine twitter without any of the functionality)

From my thinking I will be using the following:

Client - Android Phone, application 
Server - Latop, tomcat, servlet, browser

The idea is the application will use Wi-Fi to establish communication between the phone and the laptop, is it required for the android application to specify the use of the phones 3g or Wi-Fi connection in the code. Would sockets be an appropriate choice for establishing a connection? How would I go about defining the server to remain open and active looking for incoming connections from a mobile device with which to output the text communicated via a browser.

I am so vauge but I am assuming I would need to create the Android Application first, open a connection to the IP and Port of the laptop using a socket connection. Using buffer reader and printwriter communicate a users inputed text from the Android application to a servlet on the server side. Within the server a simple out.print to the browser should suffice?

Any thoughts, guidance would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you just open an http connection using HttpConnection class? just search for httpclient android.
(or open http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

then you can connect to any web server out there ...

Comment: Thanks Jay, useful place to start!